# Permissions denied on a folder the user owns (ubuntu linux)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ownership

I've created a subdirectory and assigned permissions will full r/w/x access granted to the user 'vvanglers':

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 vvanglers team 4096 Feb 18 20:48 vvanglers
```

However, when I su or ssh at the vvanglers user I get the error:

```
$ cd vvanglers
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to vvanglers
```

This directory is also the user's home directory:

```
# finger vvanglers
Login: vvanglers                Name: 
Directory: /var/www/flybook/gone/websites/v/vvanglers   Shell: /bin/sh
```

The goal here is to grant access to their home folder only and lock them out of the parent directories (shared environment). I'm not a sysadmin but it seems like the permissions look fine to me : / any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like giving +x (0755) to the parent directories worked. As long as write is disabled I don't *think* there should be any issues here, hopefully this helps someone out!

Comment: You should add this as an answer.